# Accidentally tried to regex an array-ref and extracted the word 'linux'

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I was casually writing a subroutine to do a basic regex and return a matched value.  I didn't realize my input wasn't coming in as a scalar (array-ref) and with the following code, I was returned the word 'linux'.

```
sub extract_currency {
    my ($self, $price) = @_;

    $price =~ m/^(.*)[\s?]\d/;

    return $1;
}
```

Can anyone give some insight to what was happening on a Perl/C level by running a memory location through a regex?  Never came across this before and am curious on how I was able to seemingly extract system information as a result.

Comment: Is `[\s?]` supposed to match an optional space? Or is it supposed to match a single space or question mark? Because it matches the latter.

Answer (score 4):

`$1`, `$2`, etc. are set when there's a successful match. They are not unset if a match fails. You're seeing the value of `$1` from a previous match in the same scope, e.g.

```
sub extract_currency {
    my ($self, $price) = @_;

    $price =~ m/^(.*)[\s?]\d/;

    return $1;
}

'linux' =~ /(\w+)/;

extract_currency(); # returns 'linux'
```

See the explanation in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).

For this reason, you should always check the success of a match before using `$1`, e.g.

```
sub extract_currency {
    my ($self, $price) = @_;

    if ($price =~ m/^(.*)[\s?]\d/) {
        return $1;
    }

    return undef;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
sub extract_currency {
    my ($self, $price) = @_;

    my ($currency) = $price =~ m/^(.*)[\s?]\d/;

    return $currency; # could be undef
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Can anyone give some insight to what was happening on a Perl/C level by running a memory location through a regex?*

A regex match requires a string, so it will stringify its operand. The following shows the stringification of references to an unblessed array and a blessed array:

```
$ perl -e'my $ref = []; CORE::say($ref)'
ARRAY(0x23cb218)

$ perl -e'my $ref = []; bless($ref, "Class"); CORE::say($ref)'
Class=ARRAY(0x29429e8)
```

So,

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say( [ "Foo", "Bar" ] =~ /Foo/ ? "match" : "no match" )'
no match

$ perl -e'CORE::say( [ "Foo", "Bar" ] =~ /ARR/ ? "match" : "no match" )'
match
```

---

What you possibly wanted:

```
sub extract_currency {
    my ($self, $price) = @_;
    return $price =~ /^([^\d\s]+)/ ? $1 : undef;
}

$o->extract_currency($prices->[0])
```

Note: Your pattern was broken since it would match everything up to (but excluding) the last digit. It also used `$1` without checking if the match succeeded, leading to "random" output on error.